# How to know which element is clicked and toggle class to it? JS Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 `divs` like this, with class `work`:

```
<div class="work">
    <img src="panda.jpg">
    <h3>Panda</h3>
    <p>Panda eats apple.</p>
</div>
```

And I want to toggle `clicked` class to clicked `div`:

```
.clicked {
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in jquery named [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

You should attach a click event to your div and then use `this` to reference to the clicked element.

```
$('.work').click(function() {    // edited: from $(.work) to $('.work')
    $(this).toggleClass("click")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.work').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

Geez, why couldn't you just go check the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7ep3e4gn/

```js
$('div.work').click(function(){    
   $(this).addClass('clicked').siblings('div.work').removeClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.clicked {
 font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work">
    <img src="panda.jpg">
    <h3>Panda</h3>
    <p>Panda eats apple.</p>
</div>
<div class="work">
    <img src="panda.jpg">
    <h3>Panda2</h3>
    <p>Panda2 eats apple.</p>
</div>
<div class="work">
    <img src="panda.jpg">
    <h3>Panda3</h3>
    <p>Panda3 eats apple.</p>
</div>
```

I've used `addClass` & `removeClass` along with `jQuery` **siblings** method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a method just for that.

```
$('.work').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.work').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

The `.closest()` is in case the click was registered on the contained image, etc.

Comment: You'd use `$(this)` inside your click function, not `closest()`.

Comment: @Iscmaro, good call. `.closest` is a habit - I've written a lot of code where (for ex) clicks on a table cell affect the whole row in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one of the div's with the class `.work` to have the `.clicked` class at a time, here's what you do:

```
$('.work').on('click', function() {    //When the div 'work' is clicked

   $('.work').removeClass('clicked'); //Remove the class 'clicked' from all divs named 'work'

   $(this).addClass('clicked');     //Add the class 'clicked' to the div that was clicked.

});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqy5ybnc/) for the same.